Electroacoustic guitar pickups with solid wood
I recently saw somewhere that the quality of wood is not reflected in a better electroacoustic signal received by the pickups of nylon-strung guitars. And that it is better to have some low-quality but solid wood to play the guitar when plugged in.
I would like to know if this is really true; does anyone know? What influences the sound most in electroacoustic pickups?

"low quality but solid wood" - IMHO this clause doesn't make a lot of sense. If a guitar is made from 100% solid wood, I personally would not consider it "low quality". Beyond that, why not simply buy one single guitar. Make it 100% solid wood with good acoustic tone and get it with a pickup so you can plug it in if necessary. With that plan, it doesn't matter how much the acoustic tone adds to the pickup tone - you want both so buy both in one guitar, instead of two separate guitars.

@ToddWilcox - 'make it 100% solid wood with good acoustic tone and get it with a pickup'. Is there a solid bodied guitar available without a pickup?

@Tim “Solid body” and “solid wood” are two different concepts. The question is about nylon string acoustic guitars. Cheap acoustic guitars are available with laminated woods which are not solid, they are laminated. “Solid wood” means not laminated. It doesn’t mean “solid body”.

@ToddWilcox - thank you for that. I've not heard the term 'solid wood', perhaps along with several others.



I recently saw somewhere that the wood quality does not affect the signal of nylon string guitars with good electroacoustic pickups.
And that it is better if the guitar is made of solid wood when playing it amplified.

Does anyone know if these statements are true?
What influences the sound most with electroacoustic pickups?>

To some degree, the type of wood will always have some effect on the sound.  Most pickups on electric classical guitars are piezo electric pickups and the crystal inside them is compressed and released by the vibrations where the pickup is attached.  If the pickup is located inside the bridge, the type of wood the guitar is made of will have a minimal effect.  However since the bridge is attached to the top of the guitar, there is always some interaction.
If the piezo pickup is attached inside the body, the wood will have a more pronounced effect.
Some electric classical guitars have both a piezo electric pickup AND a microphone.  Any amplification due to the microphone will be dependent upon the acoustical properties of the guitar and hence, the type of wood.
Does a guitar sound better with solid wood versus laminated wood?
Most people would say yes, but it's a matter of what you like to hear.  Different types of wood, even types of solid wood, vibrate differently and produce different sounds.  Some will be brighter or darker, so it's best to try out the guitar you want to buy and see if you like the sound.
Regardless of the pickup, many experts recommend adding some EQ to tailor the sound closer to the sound of the unamplified instrument.
https://www.thatguitarlover.com/blog/tcih2s4je5jfe8e5eveljma7qnp4sd
https://www.harmonycentral.com/articles/guitars/better-sound-from-acoustic-guitar-piezo-pickups-r542/
